# how can I clear wrong typed wireless information?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I try to connect to a WPA2 wireless network detected by my wireless adapter and the default application for wireless connection under ubuntu 12.04. I typed some wrong information such as i should have chosen PEAP, but I chose a different one, and I didn't specify the CA Certificate.

Now the ubuntu application for wireless connection remembers my wrong typed information. I try to  edit the information of the wireless network, by clicking "Edit Connections...", but that wireless network doesn't show, which I guess is because I haven't connected to it successfully. I can't add it either, because i don't know how to find out its SSID, Mode, BSSID,  Device and Clone MAC Addresses, MTU, and other information

So I wonder how I can connect to the wireless network, and edit the information of the wireless network? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delete *all* system connection data:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

And restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Before connecting to a new wireless network, how shall I find out the information  for the wireless network required in the "Wireless Security" tab, i.e. the Security (e.g. WPA2), Ahthentication (e.g. PEAP), Anonymous  Identity, CA Certificate, PEAP version, Inner authentication for the detected wireless network? The network provider didn't specify them on their website, so I guessed and tried. (2) How can I find out the information for the detected  wireless network required in the "Wireless" tab, i.e. SSID, Mode, BSSID, Device and Clone MAC Addresses, MTU of the wireless network?

Comment: @Tim You really don't need any of that information, unless you are attaching to a (usually) corporate network that uses PEAP. You should be able to click the Network Manager icon and see the network listed that you wish to connect to; like this: http://jaap.haitsma.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/nm12.png Click on your network and you will be asked for the password. If your employer/landlord/etc. has allowed you to join the network, they will have given you the password to enter when asked. You needn't fill in any of the details in Network Manager at all.

Comment: Yes, that wireless network uses PEAP. In my post, I set some information wrongly because I didn't know the right information. In general, how can we find out the information on the two tabs "Wireless" and "WIreless Security" in "Edit Connections" of network manager?

Comment: Your school, employer or other owner of the network must provide it. That's what makes it secure; if you allowed to use the wireless, you will be provided all of the encryption details.